# Django taggit related post not showing on template

Tags: django, django-taggit

Recently I installed django-taggit and included in the post model. I did the views and urls files and no error. On the home page I get a few posts and 10 tags related to posts. When I click on one of the tags it goes to the right slug but the page is blank. What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code, views.py, urls.py, home.html

```
def home(request):
    tutorial_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:3]

    context = {
        'tutorial_list': tutorial_list,
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)


class TagMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        return context

class TagIndexView(TagMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))

'''urls.py'''
path('tag/<slug:slug>/', views.TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged'),

'''home.html'''
{% for tutorial in tutorial_list %}
{{ tutorial.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% for tag in tags %}
<li><a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `context_object_name` of `TagIndexView` does not match the variable name you're iterating over in `home.html` - the template is using `tutorial_list` so `context_object_name` should be `'tutorial_list'` instead of `'post'`.

```
class TagIndexView(TagMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'tutorial_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, works perfect now. I was not sure what the context_object_name does. Thank you.@azundo